# Build a nested component in React

Tags: dom, reactjs, nested

New in React, looking for a good way to build a set of nested components given a nested `props` object.

Take the following basic `props` example:

```
const props = [{
  label: 'Foods',
  children: [
    { label: 'Chicken', children: [] },
    { label: 'Pasta', children: [] }
  ]
}];
```

I would like to use this to build a nested menu:

```
<Item>
  <Label>Foods</Label>
  <Item><Label>Chicken</Label></Item>
  <Item><Label>Pasta</Label></Item>
</Item>
```

While this is a simple example, the nesting would go much deeper.

I have searched around for this, and all I am finding are pre-built components. I'm not looking for magic yet, I'm trying to understand how things work before I use other components.

What is the best way to generate a React component to efficiently render this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a component render itself. Here's a pure component example that should work:

```
const Item = ({label, children}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    {children.map(child => (
      <Item label={child.label} children={child.children} />
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Austin's answer, it could be iterative to have as many children as needed.

```
var Container = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var Items = [];
        var level = 1;
        var self = this;

        var addItem= function (filter, level) {
            filter.forEach((f)=> {

                Items.push(<Item key={f.Id} data={f} level={level} />)

                if (f.Children !== undefined && f.Children.length != 0) {
                    addFiler(f.Children, level + 1);
                }
            });
            level -= 1;
        };

        addItem(this.props.options, level);

        return (<div>{Items}</div>);
    }
});

var Item= React.createClass({
    displayName: 'filter',
    onClick: function (e) {
        this.props.onChange(this.props.data.Id);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (<div>
                <label>
                    {this.props.data.Title}
                </label>
       </div>);
    }
});
```